# In Pyramid, can I have multiple views point to the same route/URL based on the request method?

Tags: python, pyramid, http-verbs

I've inherited a project and I'm trying to make it as clean as possible. As it is now, each view just has if/else blocks that handle the different HTTP request methods (GET, POST, DELETE, etc). I would like to have a view method that can handle not only each route, but each route + request method combination.

I'm trying this

```
@view_config(route_name='foo', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def foo(request):
    return Response(json.dumps({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'GET'}))

@view_config(route_name='foo', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
def foo(request):
    return Response(json.dumpds({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'POST'}))
```

but it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: I figured it out as I was typing the question, but I thought I'd finish it out to help others. I had to rename the view methods so they were unique, so the first `foo()` became `foo_get()` and the second became `foo_post()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the function name to get_foo for GET and post_foo for POST

```
    @view_config(route_name='foo', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
    def get_foo(request):
        return Response(json.dumps({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'GET'}))

   @view_config(route_name='foo', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
   def post_foo(request):
       return Response(json.dumpds({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'POST'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

try add `xhr=True` at @view_config, and you can use class view

```
from pyramid.view import view_config, view_defaults

@view_defaults(route_name='foo')
class TutorialViews(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(request_method='GET', xhr=True, renderer='json')
    def foo_get(self):
        return Response(json.dumpds({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'GET'}))

    @view_config(request_method='POST', xhr=True, renderer='json')
    def foo_post(self):
        return Response(json.dumpds({'route' : 'foo', 'method' : 'POST'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

according Paul Yin post. 
this is true to use 
`@view_defaults(route_name='foo')`
but you dont need to use `xhr=True` in view_config.
xhr use to handle ajax requests.
also if you use json renderer no need to usding json.dump